# Почему не сохраняются данные введеные в QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

Почему не сохраняются данные введеные в  QTextEdit ? Сам файл сохраняется но данных там нет.

```
     void MainWindow::save()
    {
   QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"), "",
    tr("Text Files (*.txt);;C++ Files (*.cpp *.h)"));

    if (fileName != "") {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            // error message
        } else {
            QTextStream stream(&file);
            stream << txt->toPlainText();
            stream.flush();
            file.close();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: в приведённом отрывке ошибки не видно...

Comment: вообще проверку  на пусто следует делать if(fileName.isEmpty()), это так. Ну и еще бы я поставил проверку на txt.